# Problem with uploading building to Somnium Space throw Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, upload

I encountered a problem when loading a 3D model of a building in the Somnium Space metaverse. The model meets all requirements.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SomniumSpace.SDK.BundleObject.BuildingItemConfig.CheckLongAnimations () (at <31ae435ac6e84dfca802585535e9fd62>:0)
SomniumSpace.SDK.EditorSDK.AssetBundleConfig.BuildingItemConfigEditor.BuildAndUploadWindow () (at <6e520e0a729e4ab185bc8870b44402c3>:0)
SomniumSpace.SDK.EditorSDK.AssetBundleConfig.AssetBundleConfigEditorBase`1[T].CheckBundlesLimit (SomniumSpace.SDK.DTO.BundleCountValidationDTO countValidation) (at <6e520e0a729e4ab185bc8870b44402c3>:0)
SomniumSpace.SDK.EditorSDK.AssetBundleConfig.AssetBundleConfigEditorBase`1[T].CheckBundlesLimitSuccess (System.String successResponse) (at <6e520e0a729e4ab185bc8870b44402c3>:0)
SomniumSpace.SDK.Managers.NetworkManager+<>c__DisplayClass5_1.<CreateGetRequest>b__1 (UnityEngine.AsyncOperation asyncOperation) (at <31ae435ac6e84dfca802585535e9fd62>:0)
UnityEngine.AsyncOperation.InvokeCompletionEvent () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/AsyncOperation.cs:21)
```

[image]

Comment: What did you mean ?

Comment: Nah, never mind, the C++ tag was removed.

Comment: Maybe it's the third-last error message: "Please put gameobject with [BuildItemConfig]...".